# Sbt tasks with dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I was reading [sbt tutorial](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks), and I wanted to understand the part about task that depend on other tasks. The problem is, I created the following from that tutorial, but it does not work:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import sys.process._

object HelloBuild extends Build {
  val hwsettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    scalaVersion := "2.9.1",
    name := "sbt-build"
  )
  val intt = TaskKey[Int]("int-task")
  val intTask = intt := 1
  val sample = TaskKey[Int]("sample-task")
  val sampleTask = sample <<= intTask map { _ + 1 }

  lazy val project = Project (
    "project",
    file("."),
    settings = hwsettings ++ Seq(intTask)
  )
}
```

It says:

```
[error] /home/platon/Tor/sbt-build/project/Build.scala:21: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(1)
[error]  required: String
[error]   val sampleTask = sample <<= intTask map { _ + 1 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the task key `intt`; not the initialization of that task key.

```
val sampleTask = sample <<= intt map { _ + 1 }
```